# Cannot return null in Users _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) function?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I don't know why the _userFromFirebaseUser function will not let me return null. Not only that but I'm getting an error when I pass `_userFromFirebaseUser` to the `map()` function?

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

//user object based on FirebaseUser

Users _userFromFirebaseUser(User user){
    if (user != null){
       return Users(uid: user.uid); 
    }
    return null;
}

//auth change user stream
Stream<Users> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Do you have null safety enabled?  See https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 0):

Make return type nullable by adding "?"

```dart
Users? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user){
  if (user != null){
    return Users(uid: user.uid); 
  }
  return null;
}

  
Stream<Users?> get user {
  return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}
```

Comment: If I make the return type nullable, then when I .map(_userFromFirebaseUser) I'm getting an error that says "The argument type 'Users Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Users Function(User?)'."

Comment: auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser!) try like this

Comment: I fixed the error! thank you!